# Pushing user data from Nodejs server to Angular after successful login

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js

I try to login my user via Facebook with use of PassportJS and pass the user data to Angular.
On the server side it all looks ok with the following code for the Facebook callback in users controller:

```
exports.facebookCallback = function() {
return function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('facebook', function(err, user, email) {
        if (err || !user) {
            return res.redirect('/auth');
        }
        req.login(user, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.redirect('/auth');
            }
            return res.redirect('/');
        });
    })(req, res, next);
 };
};
```

From what I understand from the PassportJS docs, calling req.login should put user data into the session.

My routes on the server side looks following:

```
app.get('/auth', usersCtrl.auth);
app.get('/auth/signout', usersCtrl.logout);
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    scope: ['email', 'user_hometown']
}));
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', usersCtrl.facebookCallback());
```

express and passport configuration includes:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({secret: '1234567890QWERTY'}));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Now on the angular side I try to get the user data from the session in a service defined like this:

```
module.exports = require('angular')
.module('HomeModule', [])
.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope) {
       //home controller code ors here
}).controller('NavbarCtrl', ['$scope', 'Authentication', function ($scope, Authentication) {
    $scope.authentication = Authentication;
    //rest of the navbar controller goes here
}]).factory('Authentication', [
    function() {
        var _this = this;

        _this._data = {
            user: window.user
        };

        return _this._data;

    }
]);
```

Unfoortunately, the user data is not available in window.user on angular side. 
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Is `window.user` your means of passing the user from the server to the client on a page load? If so, has this actually been set?

Comment: Not really. I'm new to JS world, so I may not understand everything. Here is how I see it: the req.login function from PassportJS puts the user data into the session (and it's been confirmed by debugging), now on the client side this session variable is available in the window object. Am I wrong here?

Comment: Passport makes your authenticated user available to express via `req.user`, but this won't be available in the client (where `window` exists) unless you set it as such. Can you include above the function that's rendering your index page?

Comment: Here is the rendering part: module.exports = function(req, res) {
 res.render('index', {
        user: req.user || null
    });
};

Comment: You're angular code should really be rendered only once, initially, and then make the authentication call on it's own.  You might want to have a look at [Angular's $resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) API for more information.

Answer (score 4):

As Girish said, the passport session object won't be available on client side. As you seem to be using `express`, a simple way to do this is to use [express-expose](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-expose).

If you want the user data to be available on all pages when the user is authenticated, you can add something like this before your routes declaration

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) res.expose(req.user, 'user');
    next ();
});
```

The user data will be available client side as `window.user`.

Answer (score 3):

The passport session object won't be available on the window object , instead you need to get it from the server using some service or a redirect url.

After successful authentication , the primary route function  will be called,
which, in this case, will redirect the user to the home page.

```
   app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', 
     passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
     function(req, res) {
     res.redirect('/');
   });


   app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index', { user: req.user });
   });
```

or you can create a route to get the logged in user data

```
   app.get('/account', function(req, res){
     if (req.isAuthenticated()) { 
       res.send({user : req.user}); 
     }else{
       res.redirect('/login');
     }
   });
```

On the Angular side, you can set the user data to rootscope from the $http response,

```
$rootScope.session = {}
$rootScope.session.user = res.user;
```